# jq toggle to do more work

Tags: jquery, toggle

I am using a simple toggle function to drop down a menu over, and I also wish to rotate the mobile menu icon image when clicked. Can this be done within this function or do I need to add a new event listener to the image?

```
jQuery('#mobile-menu-icon').click(function() {
        jQuery('#mobile-menu').slideToggle('slow', function() {

        });
```

Comment: Yes, it can: what's your (*relevant*) HTML?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes you can... Actually this is the right way to do it... the callback function inside `slidetoggle` is called when `slideToggle` completes...

```
 jQuery('#mobile-menu-icon').click(function() {
    jQuery('#mobile-menu').slideToggle('slow', function() {
           //do your rotation here
    });
 });
```